# HTML / Javascript module

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, module

As part of our application, we need to be able to provide to our clients some kind of module that they can easily inject into their own website.

The module is a form with predefined fields (we control that of course) and when the user clicks the submit button, the content of the form should be sent to us.

We have to take into account the validation. A first pass will be done on the page itself (Javascript) and another pass will be done on then server that can then return the errors to the client.

I'm looking for the best option to embed that behavior in our client website.

We thought about an iframe with a call to our server to get the html/js but I'm not sure that's the best.

We are using ASP.Net MVC with Web API 2 so I could build most of the form using razor and handle the validation like that (easy way) but I'm looking for the most portable/reusable solution as we want to avoid to have to redo the whole thing if the client changes technology.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this as a simply incorporated script rather than using directly requested content from your system, it would be best to entirely decouple the panel from the back end, so the front end is pure JavaScript, HTML and CSS performing client-side validations, then using AJAX to pass the data back to your system for server side recording and validation, bearing in mind the restrictions of [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can return the outcome of validation and display it in the page.

Unless your form is exceptionally complex, this would be simple to implement with JQuery and using a RESTful approach - through something like the [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) - to receive the requests from your side.

Both methods have positives and negatives but falling outside the DOM means that an IFrame is harder to incorporate into a page design.

Comment: Yeah I was reading on how to create a custom jQuery module and that looks like the way to go. A simple library that loads ($( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );) the html with the related js and web api behind that for the communication.

Answer (score 0):

From experience I would advise using an `<iframe>` after all. The alternative is some kind of API, but the knowledge that goes into designing a safe public facing API and unlocking it's advantages is not something worth investing time in under most circumstances. Additionally the `<iframe>` method has a lot of flexibility in regards to later changes that an API does not offer. The only 'important' part to remember is making a simple tool to customize the looks of the iframe (such as background colour, text colour, error box colours etc.)